# How to carry identity/auth from Android app to server?

Tags: android, firebase-authentication

I started using firebase auth with google and while that works I'm unsure how I can transfer a user's identity to a server call. For example

1. User authenticates in my Android app. I know they are xyz@gmail.com
2. Now I need to make a call to the server (not firebase/app engine) and the server needs to know this is user xyz@gmail without reauthenticating. I thought I'd send the auth-token and then I could verify it on the server with same id/secret, but the auth-token that I get back from IdpResponse does not work.

Any ideas on the recommended solution for this situation? Thanks

Comment: when you send the token back to firebase from your server, what kind of error message do you receive?

Comment: {
  "code" : 401,
  "errors" : [ {
    "domain" : "global",
    "location" : "Authorization",
    "locationType" : "header",
    "message" : "Invalid Credentials",
    "reason" : "authError"
  } ],
  "message" : "Invalid Credentials"
}

Comment: BTW, I'm using google oauth2:   GoogleCredential credential = new GoogleCredential().setAccessToken(accessToken);
  Oauth2 oauth2 = new Oauth2.Builder(new NetHttpTransport(), new JacksonFactory(), credential).setApplicationName("Oauth2").build();
  Userinfoplus userinfo = oauth2.userinfo().get().execute();

Answer (score 0):

This is well documented on firebase

https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/admin/verify-id-tokens

Works beautifully. I'm still not sure why the auth token doesn't work with the google oauth client.